# Does Cross-origin resource sharing affect all clients that connect to a web method?

Tags: javascript, c#, cors

I have a web method that I want to call from my C# app and was provided with a Javascript example, showing how to call the method. I have established that running the Javascript from my desktop runs into CORS problems - i was able to run the sample when I put the javascript on the server and ran it from the same folder as the web method.

Will my C# app run into the same CORS issue? or will it be ok because only the browsers have the built in CORS security?

--Edit--

I've been using System.Net.Http.HttpClient and http://restsharp.org/

Am I correct in assuming that these two objects are wrappers around a web browser? and that they will have issues with CORS?
I really don't want to have to write Sockets code.

Comment: CORS is a browser thing, so, yeah, making http requests from C# should not have any CORS issues

Answer (score 1):

Due to security reasons browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts on the browser. For example, XMLHttpRequest follows the same-origin policy. That means a web application using XMLHttpRequest could only make HTTP requests to its own domain. This prevents application from being vulnerable to CSRF attacks. However, there are cases when applications need to access resources from different domain. This is when CORS comes into play to allow cross-domain requests.

Having said all that, your C# app should be able to call the WEB API without any CORS issues as long as it's a socket to socket communication (not via browser).

Answer (score 0):

Some where in deep recess of my mind I remember browser related cors will always be blocked unless noted or changed like for example if you're in chrome and have the cors extension allow browser cors control, but on the server side, their is nothing preventing servers from interacting with one another.

but it depends on what is allowed on the headers

I'll try to produce some documentation that confirms that.

https://spring.io/understanding/CORS

The request includes an Origin header that indicates the origin of the client code.

The server will consider the request's Origin and either allow or disallow the request. If the server allows the request, then it will respond with the requested resource and an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response. This header will indicate to the client which client origins will be allowed to access the resource. Assuming that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header matches the request's Origin, the browser will allow the request.

On the other hand, if Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing in the response or if it doesn't match the request's Origin, the browser will disallow the request.